# Why aren't pip-installed executables available from the command line?

Tags: python, homebrew, pip

I've installed Python with Homebrew. I would like to use `pip` to install additional packages, some of which come with executables that are meant to be called from the command line, for example `crossbar` or `virtualenv-tools`.

But this doesn't work and I don't know why:

```
$ pip install virtualenv-tools
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-tools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ virtualenv-tools
-bash: virtualenv-tools: command not found
$ find /usr/ -name virtualenv-tools
/usr//local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv-tools
```

So `pip` correctly installed the `virtualenv-tools` package, including the executable, but somehow doesn't make this executable available to the command line.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

There is no `virtualenv-tools` executable in the `virtualenv-tools` package, that's why you cannot execute it. It contains a script called `virtualenv`, which you should be able to execute. Read the [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#usage) on how to use it first:

> Virtualenv has one basic command:
>
> ```
> $ virtualenv ENV
> ```

Anyway, in general, when you install a package using `pip` and it contains an executable script, it's put into the directory which should be in the `PATH` environment variable to be able to execute it from anywhere. This directory depends on the system used:

- Linux: `/usr/bin`
- Mac: `/usr/local/bin` (when Homebrew Python is used)
- Windows: `<python_directory>/Scripts`

So first, make sure the directory is in `PATH` (this is mainly an issue on Windows; Linux and Mac have it by default). Second, check if the script is in the directory and is executable.

Also, many packages are just libraries without any executable, so you should always *read the package documentation first* to find out how to use it.

Comment: While macOS is Unix, Homebrew does not use `/usr/bin`. It uses `/usr/local/bin` instead.

Comment: The `virtualenv-tools` package is not the same as the `virtualenv` package, and does indeed provide a `virtualenv-tools` executable: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv-tools. I have the same problem with installing `crossbar` with `pip install crossbar`: the `crossbar` executable is not available from the command line.

Comment: "when you install a package using pip and it contains an executable script" . How do we tell _pip_ to do that?